# Returning checkbox ID values, to use as corresponding variable names in a function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that I want to pass variables into via their corresponding checkbox ID values upon submission, however when I try this with the following code the function itself returns "undefined".

```
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const ids = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked'))
    .map(item => item.id)
    .join(', ');
    

    myFunction(ids)
});
```

Thinking maybe I'm going about this in the wrong way or I'm missing something fundamental.

It does not return an error, I'm guessing the strings aren't being recognised as variables.

Any help would be much appreciated, can't seem to get past this

Cheers

**Edit:** I realise my initial code and explaination might not have given enough context, my apologies. Thank you for your answer, I'll clarify below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" id="mLine" value="mLine">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hLine" value="hLine">
        <input type="checkbox" id="pLine" value="pLine">
        <button type="submit" value="send">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <button id="result">
        test
    </div>

    <script>
        const mLine = "test1"
        const hLine = "test2"
        const pLine = "test3"

        const qna = document.getElementById('result')
        const form = document.querySelector('form');

        function myFunction() {
            const arg = arguments[Math.floor(Math.random()*arguments.length)]
            qna.innerHTML = arg
        }

        form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
         e.preventDefault();

        const ids = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked'))
        .map(item => item.id)
        .join(', ');
    

        myFunction(ids)
});

    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to grab the ID from from the checkbox and parse it through the function seen as the variable of the same name, returning test1, test2, or test3 as a result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works perfect when you submit the form:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" name="1" id="1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="2" id="2">
        <input type="checkbox" name="3" id="3">
        <input type="checkbox" name="4" id="4">
        <input type="checkbox" name="5" id="5">
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
    <script>
        const myFunction = (ids) => {
            console.log(`ids: ${ids}`)
        }
        const form = document.querySelector('form')
        form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
            e.preventDefault();
          
            const ids = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked'))
              .map(item => item.id)
              .join(', ');
              
              myFunction(ids)
          });
        </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

To answer to your edited question:

You are calling the function with one argument:

```
myFunction(ids)
```

But you are declaring the a function without a parameter:

```
myFunction()
```

So you need to declare it as follow:

```
function myFunction(arguments)
```

This code will suit your needs:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" id="mLine" value="mLine">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hLine" value="hLine">
        <input type="checkbox" id="pLine" value="pLine">
        <button type="submit" value="send">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <button id="result">
        test
    </div>

    <script>
        const availableResults = {
            "mLine" : "test1",
            "hLine" : "test2",
            "pLine" : "test3"
        }
 
        const qna = document.getElementById('result')
        const form = document.querySelector('form');

        function myFunction(arguments) {
            const argumentsWithouSpaces = arguments.replaceAll(' ', ''); 
            const argumentsAsArray = argumentsWithouSpaces.split(',')
            const arg = argumentsAsArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*argumentsAsArray.length)]
            const result = availableResults[arg]
            qna.innerHTML = result
        }

        form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
         e.preventDefault();

        const ids = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked'))
        .map(item => item.id)
        .join(', ');
    

        myFunction(ids)
});

    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I appreciate it. I've added an edit for further clarification as I don't think I was very clear with the goal of my code

Comment: You're an absolute champion, this solved all my problems (including a similar issue where I wanted to refer to a pre-made list of objects), and I appreciate the explanation. Thanks mate